# how do i use Html.Action() method outside the context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to use `HtmlHelper.Action` method to generate html string outside the context. what is the best possible way? By initializing `HtmlHelper` instance or any other way?

bellow is my code inside a Generic Handler

```
async void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (socket.State == WebSocketState.Open && commTableData != null)
        {
            ArraySegment<byte> buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1024]);
            buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
            Html.Action("CommandTable", "Server", new { p = commTableData.p, CLINAME_id = commTableData.CLINAME_id, SYSCOMM_id = commTableData.SYSCOMM_id }))); // this is where i want to use HtmlHelper.Action() method
            await socket.SendAsync(buffer, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        timer.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: what about passing `htmlHelper` object to outside the controller? is it work for you?

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you're asking. Could you clarify what "outside the controller" means in your context?

Comment: yes, outside the context

Comment: Where do you want to call it? Share the code where you trying to use `HtmlHelper.Action`

Comment: inside a Generic Handler.

Comment: Show us your Generic Handler and how you are using it. Otherwise we won't know what you trying to achieve.

Comment: If you want to use HtmlHelper.Action method to generate html string outside the controller,

Then you can use .cshtml view file and generate it there. Is that what you want?

Comment: If you want to create a c# method to call on a razor view, you can use WebViewPage.

Comment: @DilshanJayaweera you want to call another action in this method?

Comment: yes, I want to call another action outside the context and get the result as html string

Answer (score 0):

If you're outside of any web context you can't. So create an url and get the reponse using Webrequest.